# logrotate prerotate script not getting name of file to be rotated

Tags: logrotate

I am having trouble with the prerotate script in logrotate 3.12.2. The script I specify in the `prerotate/endscript` section is not receiving the name of the file to be rotated as the first argument (`$1`).

Here is the logrotate configuration:

```sh
compress
/external-logs/syslog {
  daily
  rotate 3
  olddir OLD
  missingok
  prerotate
    /root/filter-syslog.sh
  endscript
}
```

Here is `/root/filter-syslog.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh 
echo "log file subject to prerotate: $1"
```

Finally, here is the verbose output of the logrotate run:

```
reading config file /external-config/logrotate.conf
olddir is now OLD
Reading state from file: /external-logs/logrotate.state
Allocating hash table for state file, size 64 entries
Creating new state

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /external-logs/syslog  after 1 days (3 rotations)
olddir is OLD, empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /external-logs/syslog
  Now: 2017-09-24 13:35
  Last rotated at 2017-09-23 12:50
  log needs rotating
rotating log /external-logs/syslog, log->rotateCount is 3
dateext suffix '-20170924'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /external-logs/OLD/syslog.3.gz to /external-logs/OLD/syslog.4.gz (rotatecount 3, logstart 1, i 3), 
old log /external-logs/OLD/syslog.3.gz does not exist
renaming /external-logs/OLD/syslog.2.gz to /external-logs/OLD/syslog.3.gz (rotatecount 3, logstart 1, i 2), 
old log /external-logs/OLD/syslog.2.gz does not exist
renaming /external-logs/OLD/syslog.1.gz to /external-logs/OLD/syslog.2.gz (rotatecount 3, logstart 1, i 1), 
old log /external-logs/OLD/syslog.1.gz does not exist
renaming /external-logs/OLD/syslog.0.gz to /external-logs/OLD/syslog.1.gz (rotatecount 3, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /external-logs/OLD/syslog.0.gz does not exist
log /external-logs/OLD/syslog.4.gz doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
running prerotate script
log file subject to prerotate: 
renaming /external-logs/syslog to /external-logs/OLD/syslog.1
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
```

Note the line "`log file subject to prerotate:`" in the above output. Why isn't the line output "`log file subject to prerotate: /external-logs/syslog`" instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not passing anything to your shell script. So `$1` in your `/root/filter-syslog.sh` has no value and therefore nothing is printed.

```sh
echo "log file subject to prerotate: $1"
```

To make it work, you have to pass `$1` or `$@` in your logrotate configuration.

```sh
compress
/external-logs/syslog {
  daily
  rotate 9
  olddir OLD
  missingok
  prerotate
    /root/filter-syslog.sh $1
  endscript
}
```